# Model person to be able to have 1 or more first names out of which one is primary

Tags: django, django-models

This is my Person class. How should I modify this to make person be able to have 1 or more first names out of which one is primary?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='persons')

    identity_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

Comment: Do you mean an fk to `PersonFirstName` or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I don't think that you have misunderstood, it's just that I am still very basic in my knowledge about hot to build Django models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another model to store the person names, something like:

```
class PersonName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can access the names from any person object using `person.personname_set`